# Even 8GB memory is getting exhausted for converting a 3GB CSV to JSON

Tags: php, json, csv, memory

I have a 3GB CSV file.

`set memory_limit = 8192M` in php.ini

```
php -r 'echo json_encode(array_map("str_getcsv", file("index.csv")));' > index.json
```

Still exhausted 8GB - now I have only 16GB RAM on my Mac - how much php memory is required for this ?

I'll probably run this on an Azure VM with 64GB RAM and shut down within 24 hrs ?

Comment: Delete the first 6 lines from https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.csv - I want to automate pushing this to Redis every week.

Comment: But now I can't read the JSON file any way. ```php script.php > index.json
head -n 10 index.json 
head: Error reading index.json
```

Comment: Thanks again - just realized that AWS provides and equivalent JSON file at https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json